# Learning error of mlogit

Tags: r, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I am using the **mlogit** R package.

For a subset of my dataset, `mlogit` is learned ok. For another subset of my dataset, I get this error.

> Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.12239e-16

When I looked for this error in contexts outside of mlogit, one suggested remedy it to use `qr.solve()` instead of `solve.default()`.

1. How do I modify mlogit to use `qr.solve()`?
2. What in my data can possibly be causing this problem?
3. Can this error result from a certain category being fully predictable from some attribute?
4. How do I check?

Comment: Mlogit is regression model. The most likely problem is that your regressors are linearly related. Using different methods will not change the problem. Supply more details about your data.

Comment: This error can also come if you specify an alternative-specific variable as being generic. Did you remember to `|` your formula, as in `mlogit(DV ~ Generic | Alt.Spec)`. Maybe you already checked this.